# how to select instances from ontology with given object property and data property values with sparql?

Tags: select, sparql, instance

Hi friends this is the part of my owl file. I need a select sparql code for my app. For example select instances who studies M201 and CS101, first_name=Josef and studentId=266814

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#"
 xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:uni="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#"
 xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2"/>
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#Student1">
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#Student"/>
<studies rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#CS101"/>
<studies rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#M201"/>
<studies rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#M204"/>
<first_name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Josef</first_name>
<last_name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Baker</last_name>
<studentID rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">266814</studentID>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

Comment: why did yo not try anything before? I mean, it's part of an assignment, right? You should maybe start reading about RDF and SPARQL first. There are good tutorials online, even for beginners. Also the official W3C docs are quite informative.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make reading it easier, here's the Turtle conversion (it basically writes the `WHERE` clause itself):

```
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix ns0: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2> a owl:Ontology .
<http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#Student1>
  a owl:NamedIndividual, <http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#Student> ;
  ns0:studies ns0:CS101, ns0:M201, ns0:M204 ;
  ns0:first_name "Josef"^^xsd:string ;
  ns0:last_name "Baker"^^xsd:string ;
  ns0:studentID 266814 .
```

So your SPARQL query would look something like

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX ns0: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?firstName ?lastName
WHERE
{
    ?student a owl:NamedIndividual ;
        ns0:first_name ?firstName ;
        ns0:last_name ?lastName ;
        ns0:studentID ?studentID ;
        ns0:studies ns0:M201 ;
        ns0:studies ns0:CS101 .

    FILTER (?studentID = 266814 && ?firstName = "Josef") .
}
```

In the `WHERE` clause, you just describe the RDF graph structure you are requiring the results to match :)

Comment: @JackJacky thanks! If you wouldn't mind accepting this as the answer, that'd be great!